# What is the proper flow in OpenID Connect/JWT after initial login?

Tags: google-openid, openid-connect

I am investigating how to implement OpenID Connect with Google's implementation and I am unclear how to handle token-based request authentication with the user following the initial receipt of the ID token. My question is - what is the "standard" practice? It seems that I have two options, at least.

1. Pass the OIDC provider's ID token to the client JS in either a header or cookie, and have have subsequent REST API calls pass the token in a Bearer header (with validation on the server side for each request).
2. Generate a new JWT and follow the same protocol as in #1.

When JWTs reach expiration, what is the best way to proceed? Is the typical process to automatically generate a new one if my application is generating a JWT (option #2)? If using the OIDC provider's token as the auth token (option #1), is it typical to repeat the authentication process with prompt=none?

I'm also curious if there are alternatives to using a 'state' value that gets stored in server session during login. I would like to avoid creating a server-specific session. Is it safe to use a JWT for the state and validate it when received back from the client with the authorization code?

I am only interested in the authentication capabilities and the additional APIs offered by OAuth are not needed at this point.